# Displaying each item in an array a number of times

Tags: php, html

Hi guys this seems to be a very basic question,
I have an array of categories, and would like to display each one 4 times.they are all floating left, so each category is displayed as a row of 4 boxes.

however there are some divs which are boxes with border that are displayed with each iteration. It seems to be working but i dont know if it's the correct way to do it, as all the
categories are not organised. I want a header of the specific category to appear first thing  each time the loop jumps to the next item in array;
Any help is welcome. please see code below.

```
[CODE]
<section class="prodList">
                <?php  
                 $loop = 4;
                 $prodNum = 0;


                 $categories =    array("All","Clothes","Gadgets","Games");


                 foreach($categories as $cat){                       
                    echo "<h2> new cat: ".$cat."</h2>";
                     while($prodNum < count($categories)*$loop){


                            echo "<div class='viewerWishlistProdContainer'>

                                        <div class='prodImageContainer'>

                                        </div>

                            </div>
                            ";
                             echo "  <p>
                                            <button class='sortBtns' onClick='alert(\'See all V'\)'>See all V</button>

                                        </p>";

                            $prodNum ++;                        

                         }



                 }
```

[/CODE]

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: 1- Is this the right way for displaying each item in an array a number of times? 2 - any ideias on why the categories <h2> are not showing up before another iteration on the categories? I have one on before the first category, and then the other jump after the last iteration is completed.

Comment: I ran your code and saw the `button` repeat many times. From your description and the result of your code, it is difficult to see what you are trying to achieve. You said your code is working. Is it supposed to repeat a button each time?

Comment: So for example, you want to display "All" 4 times in a row and a sort button after that?

And then you want to repeat this for each category?

Comment: Or are you looking to display `[All],[Clothes],[Gadgets],[Games]` in a row and have it repeat 4 times?

Comment: no! I want one row of 4 for each category:                                                            All [all] [all] [all] [all]                                       Clothes [clothes][clothes][clothes][clothes]                            Gadjets [gadjets][gadjets][gadjets][gadjets]                                  ....

Comment: the problem is that the title should'nt repeat, and also the button should be one for each row or category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
<section class="prodList">
<?php  

$categories =    array("All","Clothes","Gadgets","Games");


foreach($categories as $cat){                      
  /** Since you know it should repeat four times, why not echo 4 times? */ 
  echo "<h2> new cat: ".$cat."</h2>";
  echo "<div style='display:inline-block;padding:5px'>". $cat . "</div>"; 
  echo "<div style='display:inline-block;padding:5px'>". $cat . "</div>";
  echo "<div style='display:inline-block;padding:5px'>". $cat . "</div>";
?>
<!-- You don't have to echo plain HTML -->
<div class='viewerWishlistProdContainer'>

  <div class='prodImageContainer'>

  </div>
</div>
<p>
    <button class='sortBtns' onClick='alert(\'See all V'\)'>See all V</button>
</p>    
<?php  } /** closing the foreach block */ ?>
</section>
```

Comment: it doesn't work the way I want, but it helped :D                        I modified the "echo "<div style='display:inline-block;padding:5px'>". $cat . "</div>""   By  "<div class='viewerWishlistProdContainer'>

  <div class='prodImageContainer'>

  </div>"and it works! thanks for all the help, Cheers :)

Comment: I think you might have to wait 15 mins from the time I answered then hit the tick button below the vote number in the answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235